# Is there a way to defense from man on the ground with gun while standing?

Tags: self-defense, recommendation, safety, krav-maga, firearms

There is a situation, while fighting, your opponent falls down and draws out a gun. He is on the ground and you stand up. What is the offered solution for such a situation? Is there any? Is there a way to control or retention of the opponent? In Krav Maga, there are several techniques for situations that the opponent threats with gun, but you both in standing position and the gap is relatively small. Is there any solution for the case I mentioned before where you stand and the opponent in the ground holding gun? Demonstration videos are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have very little to work with here. The solution is probably arguably usually to raise your hands and try to placate him "OK, you won, whatever you want, man". If he started the fight by being in a psycho rage, or you think he's on drugs or a gangbanger, i.e., you think he's going to shoot you, and you're more than a few feet from him, pivot, duck, run, and zigzag. It's hard to hit a target with a pistol if you're adrenalized. Even that trained officer who got in a good stance and shot/executed that limping-away guy in the back in South Carolina in 2015 missed one or two of his ~8 shots.

Comment: Thanks @AmorphousBlob! I would like to know, how will your answer change in case your legs are very close to him, or if you have a partner behind him? Or alternatively if you watch him while drawing out a gun (or something else) from your experience do you still have time to act? In addition, in Krav Maga, there is a drill for disarm submachine gun shooter (while he lies on ground), is it also relevant here? See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UovCM5owOfw

Comment: Well, I don't have any "experience" at this per se, thankfully. If he's fumbling with the gun, you might have a chance to jump on him and grab for the gun, which even if you're young and agile would take close to 2 seconds. And then you'll be matching your strength against his, trying to grab the gun. Not to mention matching your ability to hit him on the head repeatedly until he's unconscious, against his, and your  willingness and ability to kill him if necessary to save yourself, against his.

Comment: (In which last case, then you'd be in jail for months awaiting trial, lose your job, be impoverished by legal fees, and have the somewhat random chance of a jury deciding you're guilty and spending years in prison.)  Your video shows forward rolls, which are cool to do, but there's zero chance of you jumping over him, grabbing the gun from his grasp, and completing the roll on the other shoulder.